# UWP Mapcontrol - add tooltip to element?

Tags: xaml, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I have a bunch of MapIcons defined similarly to this:

```
Geopoint t_pt = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = -50.05, Longitude = 22.12 });
MapIcon t_icon = new MapIcon { Location = t_pt };
t_icon.Title ="My_Title";
MainMap.MapElements.Add(t_icon);
```

These display on MainMap with no problem. But I would like to add a tooltip to each MapIcon that displays, for example, the Icon title.
I have tried this:

```
ToolTipService.SetToolTip(t_icon, "HI");
```

As a test but when I mouseover the MapIcon nothing is displayed. Tooltips work find if I mouseover other controls (such as a button or listbox), though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Tool tips only work with XAML elements - a MapIcon is not a XAML UI element.
You can either implement the tooltip yourself by listening to the MapPointerEntered/Exited event and displaying a XAML rectangle with text, or you can use XAML elements added to the map control as children instead of MapIcon for your pushpins (not recommended if you have a lot of items).